# How to get IPV4 from current device inside network in DART

Tags: dart, networking, async-await, get, ipv4

I'm trying to develop an open source script to connect to linux computers using an ssh connection. To be more specific I'm planning to do this to facilitate the work in wholesale networks that in my region change the internal ip from store to store as follows:

store1: 192.168.1.xxx
store2: 192.168.2.xxx
store3: 192.168.3.xxx

normally around here this type of wholesale has a range of fixed ips for the POS (sales computers), and goes from 201 to 253 since 254 is usually the gateway. so if you have 30 POS in a store, their ips will be from 201 to 230.

i need my code to work in any of the stores, from any wholesale network that will use the script without much difficulty.

i want to make a list of ips as follows:

`List<String> pos = ['192.168.$n.xxx, 192.168.$n.xxx, 192.168.$n.xxx'];`

"n" being the third part of the internal ip of the device that is running the script.

since this would cause employees who do not have access to the code to use it only in their own unit, since all normally have vpn closed to each other. the user must not have the option to say which store he is in, the script must know by itself

here goes all my code so far:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dart_ipify/dart_ipify.dart';

void main() async{

  final ipfull = await Ipify.ipv4();
  List<String> splitip = ipfull.split('.');
  print('IPV4: $ipfull');
  print('IPV4 in parts: $splitip');

  print('Functions: P (Power ON)     R (Reboot)     O (PowerOff)');

  String? function = stdin.readLineSync();

  List<dynamic> pdvs = [];

  print('Enter the POS numbers and type "e" to end and "c" to'
      'make a correction to an added POS');

  while (true) {
    String? input = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (input == 'e') {
      break;
    } else if(input == 'c') {
      print('What number do you want to remove?');
      String? inputc = stdin.readLineSync();
      pdvs.remove(inputc);
    } else if (input == 'v') {
      print("Current list: $pdvs");
    } else {
      pdvs.add(input);
    }
  }

  if(function == 'l'){
    print('Turning on POS $pdvs');
  } else if(function == 'r'){
    print('Restarting POS $pdvs');
    for(String p in pdvs){
      print('192.168.10.2$p');
    }
  } else if(function == 'd'){
    print('Turning OFF POS $pdvs');
  } else{
    print('unknown function');
  }

}
```

I apologize in advance for my English which is not very good.

there may be some translation error in the code because I wrote a lot in my own language and translated it here while asking this question, but the code is running perfectly and without errors. the problem is that it does not work as expected

I expected this part of the code:

```
final ipfull = await Ipify.ipv4();
  List<String> splitip = ipfull.split('.');
  print('IPV4: $ipfull');
  print('IPV4 in parts: $splitip');
```

return the internal ip of the device that runs the code

[Internal IPV4 from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl9hj.png)

which in this case would be 192.168.10.245

and then I could use **${splitip[2]}** to get the 3rd part of the ip which is what interests me

i tried to use ipify but it is returning my fortigate ip

Comment: Hello @Nevyle, what is a "fortigate ip" (in your last sentence)?

Comment: This is a fortigate https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61xq8wJpdgL._AC_SL1500_.jpg

Comment: FortiGate is a core part of the Fortinet Security Fabric and protects the enterprise network from known and unknown attacks. End-to-end security across the full attack cycle. Top-rated security validated by third parties. Internal segmentation firewall deployment for additional protection.

Comment: The "await Ipify.ipv4();" it's returning the ip of this device instead of returning the ip of the device I'm running the script on

Comment: And what does `ip addr show eth0` (or the like) give you on your device?

Comment: if my development environment was linux it would give me exactly the ip i want, but the company uses windows and i need to store that ip in a variable, not display it in the shell